# Need advice on how to make the turtle move with W,A,S,D. (Coding Noob)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is my second coding "project", but first using turtle. So I am trying to make the turtle move with w,a,s, and d. But it isn't working with my code and ideas?

```
from turtle import *
setup(1000,1000)
Screen()
title("Turtle Keys")
move = Turtle()
showturtle()

def w():
    move.forward(45)

def s():
    move.back(45)

def a():
    move.left(45)

def d():
    move.right(45)


onkey(w, "Up")
onkey(s, "Back")
onkey(a, "Left")
onkey(d, "Right")

listen()
mainloop()
```

`

Comment: I found your error and showed how to fix it below. In the future, please provide more information about what's not working and the error messages you get.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake with one of the 'Key' symbols.  "Back" should be "Down". The following works for me:

```
from turtle import *
setup(1000,1000)
Screen()
title("Turtle Keys")
move = Turtle()
showturtle()

def w():
    move.forward(45)

def s():
    move.back(45)

def a():
    move.left(45)

def d():
    move.right(45)


onkey(w, "Up")
onkey(s, "Down") # "Back"
#         ^^^^
onkey(a, "Left")
onkey(d, "Right")

listen()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey Gary!  Thanks for the quick reply it may be a problem on my end, but when I put in the code the turtle pops up on my screen but the keys don't move the turtle. Again thanks for the reply!

Comment: Are you using the Arrow keys? This works for me in Py27 and Py36.

Comment: I use the up, down, left and right arrow keys. If you want  to use the w, a, s, d keys, you have to use different strings in your `onkey()` commands, such as `onkey(w, 'w')`, etc.

Comment: Hey Gary! Thanks a ton with the onkey() command fix it works with w,a,s,d!

Comment: Great! You can actually have as many onkey() commands as you want, so if you want to support the w,a,s,d keys and the arrow keys, you can keep both sets of onkey() commands.